# How to upload multiple images to firebase database and retrieve

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to store all images in Firebase database under at index values.

[This is sample screenshot of my firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS5yt.png)

This is my photos uploading class but images are storing using single id and single image url only. How to upload multiple images to firebase database and retrieve . Please Help me and im new to firebase database multiple images uploading.

```
public class PhotoUploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private String mListID,mInspectionID;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private StorageReference storageReference;


private Button openCustomGallery;
private Button mUploadPhoto;
private GridView selectedImageGridView;

private static final int CustomGallerySelectId = 1;//Set Intent Id
public static final String CustomGalleryIntentKey = "ImageArray";//Set Intent Key Value
private List<String> selectedImages;
private GalleryAdapter adapter;
private String imagesArray;
private String timestampString;
private String formattedTimestamp;
private Long timestamp;
private int failUplaod;
private int successUpload;
private ProgressDialog uploadProgress;
private String pathPhoto;
private String remarkPhoto;
private int currentprogress;
private ImageView currentImage;
private String mTestID;
 private ArrayList<String > blogimages;
private String mKeyID, mAddress, mLocationKey, mRegion;
private HashMap<String,Object> photos = new HashMap<>();
private HashMap<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
public static boolean loaded = false;
StorageReference mstorageReference;
DatabaseReference mdatabaseReference;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
DatabaseReference userdatabaseReference;
EditText desc;
Button upload;
private ProgressDialog mProgressbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_selected);

    setTitle("Write Post");
    mProgressbar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    initViews();
    setListeners();
    mstorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mdatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userdatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
   upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_post_submit);
   desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_post_text);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            UploadTask uploadTask;
            if( selectedImageGridView.getChildCount()!= 0)
            {
                blogimages   =  new ArrayList<>();
                mProgressbar.setMessage("Post Uploading_Please Wait.....");
                mProgressbar.show();

                for ( int i = 0; i < selectedImages.size(); i++) {


                   Uri  uri = Uri.parse("file://"+selectedImages.get(i));

                    Log.v("URIIII", String.valueOf(uri));
                    final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    StorageReference reference = mstorageReference.child("Blog_pics/users").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                    uploadTask = reference.putFile(uri);

                   uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //todo: if want to make this the full progress bar, just need to make this as the sum of all progress and add to the main progress dialog
                            double progress = (100.0 * (taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                            mProgressbar.setMessage("Uploading Images.....");
                            mProgressbar.show();


                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            final Uri downloaduri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Log.v("DOWNLOAD URI", String.valueOf(downloaduri));
                            blogimages.add(downloaduri.toString());
                            Log.v("BLOGGIMAGES", String.valueOf(blogimages));
                           // final String path=  uri.getLastPathSegment();
                            final String key = mdatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                            final String posttitle = desc.getText().toString();
                            final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            userdatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                                    final   String current_time = df.format(today);
                                    Blog blog = new Blog();
                                    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    int timestamp = ((int) (millis/1000))* -1;
                                    blog.setTimestamp(current_time);
                                   blog.setTime(timestamp);
                                    blog.setTitle(posttitle);
                                    blog.setUrl(blogimages);
                                   blog.setUid(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                 blog.setUsername(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                                   blog.setImage(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                                   mdatabaseReference.child(key).setValue(blog) .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                                        {
                                            Intent mm = new Intent(PhotoUploadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(mm);
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadActivity.this,"Failed to post the blog.. Try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                                }
                            });
                            }

                    }) .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadActivity.this,"Please enter all fields and Select images.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });

    selectedImageGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotoUploadActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Delete Item?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to remove this item?")
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            adapter.removeitem(position);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            /*Or you can do it this way if the top one doesnt work:

                            selectedImageGridView.setAdapter(null);*/
                        }
                    });

            deleteDialog.create().show();


            return true;
        }
    });


}



private void initViews() {
    openCustomGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openCustomGallery);
    selectedImageGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImagesGridView);
   // mUploadPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UploadPhotos);

}

//set Listeners
private void setListeners() {
    openCustomGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.openCustomGallery:
            //Start Custom Gallery Activity by passing intent id
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhotoUploadActivity.this, CustomGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CustomGallerySelectId);
            break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent imagereturnintent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, imagereturnintent);
    switch (requestcode) {
        case CustomGallerySelectId:
            if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
                imagesArray = imagereturnintent.getStringExtra(CustomGalleryIntentKey);//get Intent data
                //Convert string array into List by splitting by ',' and substring after '[' and before ']'
                selectedImages =  Arrays.asList(imagesArray.substring(1, imagesArray.length() - 1).split(", "));
                //loadGridView(new ArrayList<String>(selectedImages));//call load gridview method by passing converted list into arrayList
                adapter = new GalleryAdapter(PhotoUploadActivity.this,new ArrayList<>(selectedImages),false);
                selectedImageGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

//I'm saving the instance state of photos.. let's see how

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("Photos",photos);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Photos");
}
}
```

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417274/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-firebase-in-android` take look from here you've to  implement like in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, store the image urls in a `Map`. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- Blog
         |
         --- blogId
               |
               --- urls
               |    |
               |    --- "https://firebasestorage...": true
               |    |
               |    --- "https://firebasestorage...": true
               |
               --- //the other blog details
```

To display all those images, just get the `urls` object, which is a map and iterate to get the keys which are actual the urls of your photos.

**Edit:**

There is also an alternative structure which looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- Blog
         |
         --- blogId
               |
               --- urls
               |    |
               |    --- pushedKeyOne: "https://firebasestorage..."
               |    |
               |    --- pushedKeyTwo: "https://firebasestorage..."
               |
               --- //the other blog details
```

Comment: same way i  tired but passing database reference with child has current user only its storing like above one but i need to store with post key i.e. final String key = mdatabaseReference.push().getKey(); like now by using the key i need to store all the images but its storing one one image only . Is there any solution r examples

Comment: If you want to use pushed key, please see my updated answer to see how the new database strcture should look like. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: no not that key , there u mention blogid and im passing this final String key = mdatabaseReference.push().getKey(); in place of blog id . By passing this key only one image url is showing but when i passing final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); there its showing two image urls

Comment: Once send me any examples of multiple images storing and retrieving them as gridview . I'm struggling from past 5 days

Comment: You can use uiter the first of my example, eiter the second you can achieve the same thing. Have you even try it?

Comment: Im passing like this but showing only one image. for ( int i = 0; i < selectedImages.size(); i++) {
Uri  uri = Uri.parse("file://"+selectedImages.get(i));
}  Uri downloaduri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() 
blogimages.add(downloaduri.toString());
final String key = mdatabaseReference.push().getKey();
userdatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
Blog blog = new Blog();
blog.setUrl(blogimages);
mdatabaseReference.child(key).setValue(blog) .addOnSuccessListener

Comment: I don't understand why you posted this code but I strongly recommend you to try my solution above and if you get stuck during a specific step, show what you've tried by posting another fresh question so me or other users can help you.

Comment: Yaa i tired but its showing one image with one blod id with username, timestamp and title and again another image also showing with another blog id with same username, timestamp and title. This is my code Map<String, Object> postValues = blog.toMap();
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/post_images/" + key , blogimages);
childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);
mdatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates)

Comment: Try to post another question, it's best to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you're using `true` as a placeholder, why not use a timestamp. It will help you sort images based on their upload time. Just saying, nothing wrong with `true`, but storing a timestamp will come in handy